# How can I find the smallest difference between values within a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

EXAMPLE DF

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 25., 24., 26., 29.]})
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
2 (because the smallest difference is between 24 and 26 of Parrot)
```

EVEN BETTER (so I can check)

```
'Parrot, 2'
```

WHAT I WAS THINKING

'I need to sort by animal and max speed, and then a window function, but there must be a better solution...'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can check `groupby` with `diff`

```
df['new'] = df.sort_values('Max Speed').groupby('Animal')['Max Speed'].diff().abs()
out = df[df.new==df.new.min()]
Out[249]: 
   Animal  Max Speed  new
4  Parrot       26.0  2.0
```

Comment: You are making the assumption that two consecutive values will always convey the minimum... Which may be the case... I dunno. Let's see what @Charles is gonna say about this.

Comment: @keepAlive if this is sorted why no just do diff ~ :-) , we can also adding sort_values to protect

Comment: Yep you are right.. As long as the OP needs the minimum.

Comment: It looks good and works so I'm happy :-). Thanks guys!